# Component is overlapping the other component

Tags: css, reactjs

I am making a dashboard for my project but got stuck on a problem, where I need to navigate to login from my dashboard. I want this login path to be seen separately from my app, but they are overlapping each other, how can I solve this?
This is my app.jsx

```
import "./App.css";
import React , { useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Container from "./components/Container/Container";
import RightNavbar from "./components/RightNavbar/RightNavbar";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import Analytics from "./components/Analytics/Analytics";
import Campaings from "./components/Campaigns/Campaigns";
import Team from "./components/Team/Team";
import Login from './components/Registeration/Login';
import NavContext from "./Context/NavContext";
function App() {
  const [nav, setNav] = useState(false);
  const value = { nav, setNav };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavContext.Provider value={value}>
        <Navbar />
        <Container
          stickyNav={<RightNavbar />}
          content={
            <Routes>
              <Route path="*" element={<main>NOT FOUND</main>} />
              <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="/analytics" element={<Analytics />} />
              <Route path="/campaings" element={<Campaings />} />
              <Route path="/team" element={<Team />} />  
              </Routes>
          }
        />
      </NavContext.Provider>
      <Routes><Route path = '/login' element = {<Login/>}/></Routes>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the picture of my dashboard, you can clearly see the login on far-right which should be displayed separately.

[image: Here is the picture of my dashboard]

Comment: didn't you `import React from 'react'`?

Comment: Sorry, it was just a typo. I have updated the question .